# Javascript using different configurations for different outputs

Tags: javascript

Hi being a complete and utter idiot at the moment, where I have staring at this stuff for hours and now have no clue what I am doing.

Basically in one which I will name here as product.js I have Global Variables fixed

```
var AREA_MAX_MAXX = 1000;
var AREA_MAX_MINX = 60;
```

these are being then being used within another js which I will call library.js with the following:

```
this.area_max_maxx = AREA_MAX_MAXX;
this.area_max_miny = AREA_MAX_MINX;

this.calcPos = function() {
  var areaMaxWidth = this.area_max_maxx - this.area_max_minx;
```

What I want to do is remove the Global Variables and instead have it set up with arrays, so that whatever the array is the values will be set for`area_max_maxx`

Can anyone help me out there??? Am I making sense?

Comment: It is difficult to understand your question, what do you want to do and why?

Comment: Basically I have a product.js where I have global variables, which are  obviously individual for each product.js. These in turn are being used in the lib.js to adjust the size and positioning of certain images, texts etc. What I want to do is consolidate all these product.js files into one, each one using its own variables as set before in the global

Answer (score 1):

You mean like this?

```
this.minAndMax = [60, 1000];
this.calcPos = function() {
  var areaMaxWidth = this.minAndMax[1] - this.minAndMax[0];
}
```

I would recommend instead using an object:

```
this.areaParameters = {min: 60, max: 1000}
this.calcPos = function() {
  var areaMaxWidth = this.areaParameters.max - this.areaParameters.min;
}
```

Later, you can just say `this.areaParameters.max = 3000` and next time `calcPos` gets called it will use the new value.

Answer (score 0):

This is not possible. You are passing a value not a reference here:

```
this.area_max_maxx = AREA_MAX_MAXX;
```